# Tumblr photoset parenting "video" attributes

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I was trying to program my own Tumblr code specifically to put a hover color (found this answer here) only in the first frame of the photoset (this also), anyway, I found another problem, I just can not work on Photoset attributes because my photoset are responding to my "video" tag; in Example:

```
<html>
   <head>
        <style>
        </style>
   </head>
   <body>
       {block:posts}
              {video-500}
       {/block:posts}  
   </body>
</html>
```

By putting the video thing in the code, the theme auto shows any photoset post, but its a video tag; How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

**Post Type Variable Blocks**

Tumblr provides a block for each post type, so you create specific markup.

```
{block:Posts}

{block:Photosets}

{/block:Photosets}

{block:Video}
{Video-500}
{/block:Video}

{/block:Posts}
```

This is only render a video `embed` if the post type is `video`.

Source: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts

Comment: thanks for the fast answer mike, let me explain different: the {block:photoset} is loaded in the code, exactly how you did above, but the photoset post only show up if the video tag is loaded, and nothing happens if only the photoset block are in the code without the video. Starting to think that its a bug from tumblr.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the entire post loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your problem. But I think I got a similar/relating problem:

I loaded up a photoset (3pics) via the dashboard where it is shown correct. But in my tumblr-blog[1](http://blog.denkeronline.de) were I put:

```
{block:photoset}          
   {photoset}   
{/block:photoset}
```

nothing is shown.

But when I put it this way

```
 {block: video}
   {photoset}
 {/block:video}
```

the photoset (!) is show correctly.

I'm googleing for that problem since last week but can't find any solution.

So this might not help for your problem, but if you solved yours I'm interested in how you do it.